# Bind data to the Syncfusion RTE inside GridView

Tags: gridview, webforms, syncfusion, rte

I am trying to bind data from GridView DataSource to the Syncfusion RTE and it doesn't work.

It works fine if I bind data to the TextBox field but not for the Syncfusion RTE.

[image]

What might be the reason for this problem and how could I bind the data to the RTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have validated your reported problem in RTE control inside of ASP GridView. The Bind data also works for the EJ RTE control. We have prepared sample for your convenience, which can be downloaded from the below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/158992/ze/GridView_RTE_bind-2036973946

Please check out the below output screenshot of the attached sample.

If the issue still persists, please share some additional details it will be help us to provide you the prompt solution.

1. If facing any script error, share us the screenshot.
2. Share the issue replicating sample or else replicate the issue in attached sample.
3. Share us the screen recorded video with issue replicating steps.

We can also raise query in Syncfusion forums.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums

Regards,

Muthukrishnan K